# RNN - LSTM model for multivariate time series

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using LSTM for time series forecasting. This is my dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKTom.png)

X1,...,5 is the multivariate time serie, y the value to predict and mean, std, var, median, volume are the additional features

Now instead of feeding the whole dataset sequence, I'd like to feed first the last 6 feature (the actual multivariate time serie X,y) into LSTM and concatenate the mean, std ecc features after the lstm layer (before/after dense layer).

This is a sort of model i draw:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crTHh.png)

How can i implement this model in keras? I'm sorry if something is confusional but i'm still learning

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

This is my model, but sequential

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear, but if it relates with 
"how do I implement this model in Keras?", then you cannot use Sequential, as it is only for models where layers feed directly into the next layer, without branches or extra inputs. You need to create a custom Model class, define the architecture and then define how to perform a forward pass (and there you have flexibility to split the sample, feed part to the LSTM and the other to the dense layer)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately i know i can't use sequential, do i find the custom class documentation? do you have some code?

Comment: You can find the documentation here: https://keras.io/api/models/model/